# apt install doesn't get the same version in different servers

Tags: apt, software-installation

I have one server with Ubuntu 20.04. When I use `sudo apt install ffmpeg` it installs version 4.2.7 from `http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`

In another server with Ubuntu 16.04, `sudo apt install ffmpeg` installs version 2.8.17 from `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`

I used `apt update` before installing, in both servers.

Does that mean version 2.8.17 is the latest version that is supported in Ubuntu 16.04?
I need all my servers to get the same version of the software.

Comment: Questions about Ubuntu 16.04 are off topic on this site. It is a long gone EOL version. There are no new anything for an EOL version.

Comment: If you want them to all run the exact same version of apps they need to be the same version of OS.

Comment: @David How is that? I can install Node 16.16.0 in various Ubuntu versions, and I face no problem. But I don't use `apt install` for that.

Comment: Because you can not. Apt update and upgrade do not work on EOL versions. You are playing with fire by just randomly deciding to install a version not intended for that version of the OS.

Comment: @David well, I see.

Comment: The reason you can install newer node is because there are external repositories maintained by node developers who keep packages around for older releases of Ubuntu. You can technically upgrade all the way from 16.04 through 18.04 to 20.04. It'll take a while and the odd thing may break along the way. But it's possible.

Comment: @popey thank you

Answer (score 2):

In general, Ubuntu aims to be *stable*. That means that for the life of the release, things should not change significantly. Interfaces should stay stable.

This also includes versions of packages. 20.04 means that you will have compatibility over the lifetime - it's unlikely that ffmpeg will change major version in 20.04. Rather, important security fixes are backported.

If you want same version from the repositories, you have to be on the same Ubuntu release. This is also the good thing about stable releases - it ensures compatibility between different machines.